# Datatables headers hiding on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, datatables

I've been using Datatables plugins around 6 months, and it's awesome. 
But today i'm facing a problem I can't understand. I debugged every single line of my application (js, css, html) to check if it's my fault, but all seems pretty good. 
Basically, my Datatables are hidding the headers of every Datatable when a responsive action comes around. This only happen in Google Chrome. Firefox, Safari, Vivaldi....All the others look nice and clean as always.

Here you have a screenshot to illustrate you: 
[image]

Code:

```
me.datTableObject = $(me.dataTableName).DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'hidden-xs col-sm-6'lC>r>" +
        "Zt" +
        "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'hidden-xs col-sm-6'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
        this.removeClass("hidden");
        $(me.dataTableName).wrap("<div class='tableWrap'></div>");
    },
    "autoWidth": false, //!IMPORTANT If this is set to true, the width will not be dynamic as we wish.
    "columns": columns,
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        if (!me.datTableObject)
            return;

        var metadata = me.datTableObject.metadata;

        if (metadata) {
            me.colorTable(metadata, nRow, iDisplayIndexFull);
        };
    }
});
```

The variables and other methods comes from a jSon call. I checked and them are good as always.

I hope you can help me, because I don't know what more to do/check. Thank you!

Comment: If you check the table in the DOM inspector, what CSS is being applied to the table header elements? My guess would be they are being hidden by a rule somewhere - possibly a responsive stylesheet somewhere

Comment: if some code is available then we can do more help in this.

Comment: Code of datatable creation added @pathaktejpal

Comment: Also, I checked what you mentioned before @RoryMcCrossan and there isn't any css hidden attributes :(